# Unix signals in Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, signals, android-broadcast

I have an Activty which loads a native library. In the native library, should I catch the unix termination signals? I have tried, but unable to trap them.

In the native library,

```
void SignalHandler (int signal)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "SignalHandler");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "signal = %d", signal);

    // Do something
}

// Will be called from MainActivity.onCreate()
void NativeFunction (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) (
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG,"NativeFunction ");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Registering for signals...");

    if (signal(SIGTERM, SignalHandler) == SIG_ERR)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Registering for SIGTERM failed!");

    if (signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler) == SIG_ERR)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Registering for SIGINT failed!");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Successfully registered for signals!");

}
```

I swiped up from the recents screen or closed the Activity by pressing the Back button...but didn't get any termination signals (lifecycle callbacks of the Activity were called - as expected).

The question is, should I be writing signal handlers to handle these (SIGINT and SIGBREAK)  signals?
I have only tested these two ways (swipe up and back button press), but there are many ways for Android to terminate an app. Will I ever get SIGTERM, SIGINT or other signals (which expects the application to exit) in the Android environment?
I haven't found anything (so far) in the docs.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected the lifetime of your native library to somehow be tied to the lifetime of a particular instance of an `Activity`(?). How are you loading the library exactly?

Comment: Do you know what async-signal-safe functions are?  I'm guessing no, and if you don't know, you shouldn't be writing signal handlers for anything until you do.

Comment: @Michael I'm aware that when the Activity gets destroyed, library is not unloaded. And when you instantiate this Activity again and again (by calling startActivity (intent)), native lib is not loaded again. This was just to see if I can catch SIGTERM in Android. I have used the default template provided by Android Studio, which loads the native lib in a static context in the MainActivity class.  Then, in MainActivity.onCreate, call NativeFunction.